# JQuery Mobile panel still not compatible with JQuery 2.0.3?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-panel, jquery-2.0

I am having a problem while loading JQM panels. I am using Jquery v2.0.3 and JQM v1.3.2.
JS console reports this as the problem:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined 
line# jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js:10330

I googled and found a few users complaining about panel being incompatible with Jquery v2.0. But that was 5 months ago. Do you know if it is still incompatible or am I doing something wrong? I am fairly new to JQM. I have put together an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DSgFz/) which uses Jquery 2.0.2 which demonstrate the problem described above. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/b3tck/2/) is the same example with Jquery 1.9.1 and it works fine.

I would really like to use JQuery 2.0.2.

Here is how I am instantiating the panels

```
<div data-role="panel" id="left_panel" data-position="left" data-display="overlay" data-theme="a" data-swipe-close="false">
        <a href="#" data-rel="close" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="right">Close</a>
</div><!-- /panel -->
```

I would appreciate any pointer. Thank you!!

Comment: it looks like 1.3.2 still doesn't support jQuery 2.0.x. However, JQM 1.4.2a supports 1.10.x and 2.0.x but it is still in alpha phase http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2013/08/15/jquery-mobile-1-4-0-alpha-2-released/#download edit: your demo using 2.0.2 and 1.4.2alpha http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/DSgFz/1/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile 1.4.+ supports all jQuyer version now :D

http://jquerymobile.com/

> jQuery 1.8 - 1.10 / 2.0